# Portmanteau theorem for finite signed Borel measures

Tags: measure-theory, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all finite signed Borel measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal M_+(X)$ the space of all finite nonnegative Borel measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal M_1(X)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$, and
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ be the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$.

Then $\mathcal C_b(X)$ is a real Banach space with supremum norm $|\cdot|_\infty$. We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ is a Banach space. For $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$, we define the weak convergence
$$
\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_b(X).
$$

Then we have Portmanteau theorem for finite non-negative Borel measures, i.e.,

> [Portmanteau theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569265/portmanteau-theorem-for-non-negative-finite-borel-measures) Let $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M_+(X)$ such that $\mu_n(X) \to \mu(X)$. Then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> - (1) $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$.
> - (2) $\lim_n \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n = \int_X f \mathrm d \mu$ for all bounded Lipschitz-continuous functions $f:X \to \mathbb R$.
> - (3) $\liminf_n \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \ge \int_X f \mathrm d \mu$ for all lower semi-continuous functions $f:X \to \mathbb R$ that are bounded from below.
> - (4) $\limsup_n \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \le \int_X f \mathrm d \mu$ for all upper semi-continuous functions $f:X \to \mathbb R$ that are bounded from above.
> - (5) $\liminf_n \mu_n(O) \ge \mu(O)$ for all open subsets $O$ of $X$.
> - (6) $\limsup_n \mu_n(C) \le \mu(C)$ for all closed subsets $C$ of $X$.
> - (7) $\lim_n \mu_n(A) = \mu(A)$ for all Borel subsets $A$ of $X$ such that $\mu(\partial A) = 0$.

I would like to ask if above theorem extends to $\mathcal M(X)$, i.e., we replace *"$\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M_+(X)$ s.t. $\mu_n(X) \to \mu(X)$"* by *"$\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$ s.t. $[\mu_n] \to [\mu]$"*. If not, are there some mild conditions on $X$ so that such an extension is possoble?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Take $\mu_n = -\delta_{1/n}\to -\delta_0:=\mu$ and $O = (0,1)$. Then $\liminf_n \mu_n(O) = -1 < 0 = \mu(O) $.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thank you for your counter-example to (5). What if we [replace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967941/show-that-%ce%bcc-sup-substackf-in-c-b-f-le1-left-f-right-cc-0-mu) $\liminf_n \mu_n(O) \ge \mu(O)$ by $\liminf_n |\mu_n| (O) \ge |\mu| (O)$ where $|\mu_n|$ is the variation of $\mu$?

Comment: As Otis Chodosh has shown condition (3), (4), (5) and (6) don't make sense for non positive measures. Only (7) may be correct, if you replace $\mu(\partial A)$ by $|\mu|(\partial A)$. Trying to replace $\mu$ by $|\mu|$ gives results about $|\mu|$, not $\mu$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Assume $X$ is locally compact. Surprisingly, Proposition 2.8.  in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.13207.pdf) paper shows that if $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ and $\limsup_n[\mu_n] \le [\mu]$ then $\mu^+_n \rightharpoonup \mu^+$ and $\mu^-_n \rightharpoonup \mu^-$.

Comment: The extension to all of $\mathcal{M}(S)$ (complex measures or signed measures of total finite variation) does not hold in general. There is however [Prohorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem#Extension) which can be found in for example, Bogachev's Measure Theory, vol 2.